# Switch off the labels on axes

Tags: user-interface, matlab, label, figure

I'm using **axes1** on a GUI to show images in. However, I don't know how to make the labels on **axes1** invisible.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just  set the XTick and YTick property:

```
a = axes(); plot(1:10,1:10);
set(a,'XTick',[],'YTIck',[])
```

Comment: You mean xticklabel and yticklabel I suppose.

Comment: To clarify bdecaf's and Nzbuu's comments -- setting `xticklabel` and `yticklabel` off will turn off the axis labels (e.g. numbers or text labels printed alongside the axes). Setting `xtick` and `ytick` off will turn off the little tick marks that appear along the axes (in addition to ALSO turning off the associated labels).

Comment: What if I am doing GUI development?
Then where should I insert this command?

Comment: @RandolphKevin, if you are using guide, you can simply edit the property of the axes